# Choose max number of non-overlapping 2x2 squares in binary bitmap

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a rectangle consisting of 1's and 0's, how can I find the maximum number of non-overlapping 2x2 squares of 1's?

Example:

```
0110
1111
1111
```

The solution would be 2.

I know it can be solved with Bitmask DP; but I can't really grasp it - after playing with it for hours. How does it work and how can it be formalised?

Comment: can you share link to problem?

Comment: Sounds a bit like the tiling problem. It looks like it's going to be really hard to solve.

Comment: I don't have any link.

Comment: Tiling problem is a good keyword, thanks!

Comment: upper bound on matrix dimensions?

Comment: Upper bound would be width 15, height 100.

Comment: Your problem resembles "DP over profile" problem. [Look here](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=697369) for  more details, section "Layer count + layer profile".

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to point out that the graph we get by putting vertices at the centers of squares and joining them when they overlap is *not* claw-free:

If we take (in the full plane) a 2x2 square and three of the four diagonally overlapping 2x2 squares, they form the induced subgraph

```
•   •
 \ /
  •
 /
•
```

This is a claw, meaning that any region containing those squares corresponds to a non-claw-free graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a graph where every node represents a 2x2 square of 1's and there is an edge between two nodes if they overlap, then the problem is now: find the maximum independent set in this graph.

Comment: It is NP-hard. It is unlikely to be fast enough for a 15x100 matrix.

Comment: Yes, i'm thinking if the resulting graph would be a special case that can be solved polynomially (bipartite for example).

Comment: I do not see a way to make it bipartite. It is unlikely to work, unfortunately.

Comment: The DP solution runs in O(2^N * N * M), where N is the width and M the height. I like the MIS idea - shame, it's not bipartite.

Comment: The problem is that one dimension is small, but the total matrix size is pretty big(which makes dp feasible). Strictly speaking, that comment does not prove that it is NP-hard(a valid proof is a reduction from a well-known NP-hard problem to this one), but I tend to believe that it is solvable in polymonial time.

Comment: @bengro Can you please explain how to solve using DP ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic programming solution.

1. The state is `(row number, mask of occupied cells, shift position)`. It looks like this:

   ```
   ..#..    
   .##..  
   .#...  
   .#...
   ```

   In this case, the row number is 2(I use zero-bases indices), the mask depends on whether we take a cell with `#` or not, the shift position is 1. The number of states is `O(n * m * 2 ^ n)`. The value of a state is the maximum number of picked 2x2 squares. The base case is `f(1, 0, 0) = 0`(it corresponds to the first row and no 2x2 squares picked so far).
2. The transitions are as follows:

   ```
   ..#..    ..#..
   .00.. -> ..1..
   .0...    .11..
   .#...    .#...
   ```

   This one can be used if and only if the square consists of ones in the original matrix and there were zeros in the mask(it means that we pick this square).
   The other one is:

   ```
   ..#..    ..#.. 
   .##.. -> ..#..
   .#...    .#0..
   .#...    .#...
   ```

   This one is always applicable. It means that we do pick this 2x2 square.
   When we are done with one row, we can proceed to the next one:

   ```
   ..#..    ..#0.
   ..#.. -> ..#..
   ..#..    ..#..
   .##..    ..#..
   ```

There are at most two transitions from each state, so the total time complexity is `O(n * m * 2 ^ n)`. The answer the maximum among all masks and shifts for the last row.

Comment: Can you please provide with some code snippet, so that that would help in understanding your solution.

Answer (score 0):

edit 20:18, there is a counterexample posted by @ILoveCoding

My intuition says, that this will work. I am unable to prove it since I'm not advanced enough. I can't think of any counterexample though.
I will try describe the solution and post the code, please correct me if my solution is wrong.

First we load input to an array.
Then we create second array of the same size and for every possible placing of 2x2 square we mark 1 in the second array. For the example posted by OP this would look like below.

```
0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

Then for every 1 in second array we calculate the number of neighbours (including diagonals) + 1 (because if it doesn't have any neighbours we have to still see it as 1). We set those new numbers to the array. Now it should look like this.

```
0 4 0 0
3 4 3 0
0 0 0 0
```

Then for every non-zero value in the array we check whether it has any neighbour with bigger or equal value. If it has then move on since it can't be in the solution. 
If we don't find any such value then it will be in the solution. We have to reset to zero every neighbour of the original value (because it can't be in the solution, it would overlap the solution.

So the first such number found should be 2 on the left. After processing it the array should look like following.

```
0 0 0 0
3 0 3 0
0 0 0 0
```

When we check the other 3 situation is the same.

We end up with non-zero values in the array indicating where top left corners of 2x2 squares are.

If you need the numer of them just traverse the array and count non-zero elements.

Another example

```
1111  ->  1 1 1 0  ->  4 6 4 0  ->  4 0 4 0
1111  ->  1 1 1 0  ->  6 9 6 0  ->  0 0 0 0
1111  ->  1 1 1 0  ->  6 9 6 0  ->  6 0 6 0
1111  ->  1 1 1 0  ->  6 9 6 0  ->  0 0 0 0
1111  ->  1 1 1 0  ->  4 6 4 0  ->  4 0 4 0
1111  ->  0 0 0 0  ->  0 0 0 0  ->  0 0 0 0
```

The code I write can be found here
http://ideone.com/Wq1xRo

Comment: Could you please modify your code so that it prints the actual answer? I think I know a test case it fails, but I cannot be sure because it doesn't print the result.

Comment: For this test case: {100011,
011111, 
111111, 
110111, 
100011, 
100011} your code prints 6, but it seems to me that the answer should be 5.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I'm thinking if checking values in order from the lowest to the highest would change that, since it can be eliminated with few passes of "//taking values with lesser neighbours" labeled loop.

Comment: I changed code (same link still). Now it prints correct value for your example, but it still may not be correct algorithm.

Comment: Here is another one: {01111,
11111,
11110,
01100}. Your solutions prints 2, but the answer is 3. So I think that your algorithm is not correct.

Comment: This one completly breaks my algorithm so i guess it can't be done like this. Thanks for giving this example.